# AWS create-cache-cluster - security group id not recognized

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group, aws-vpc

I tried to create a elastic cache using aws cli and faced an error. The security group id that I use is my accounts default security group id and I see it exists on the aws console. Not sure why it is erring out.

```
user$ aws elasticache create-cache-cluster \
>     --cache-cluster-id ClusterForLambdaTest \
>     --cache-node-type cache.m3.medium \
>     --engine memcached \
>     --security-group-ids sg-f123f123 \
>     --num-cache-nodes 1 

An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the 
CreateCacheCluster operation: Some security group Id not recognized 
by EC2: securityGroupIds[[sg-f123f123]], awsAccountId[123456789012]
```

Comment: Are you launching your cluster to a VPC ? If so are those failing security group ids belong to the same VPC that you want to create the cluster ? (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elasticache/create-cache-cluster.html)

Comment: I had a similar error today with Redshift. I had the region wrong.

Comment: try using the name of the security group instead of the id.

Comment: @auhuman - how did you fix this ?

Comment: @auhuman - did you figure out solution ?